# PHP - Can't read filesize on files without extensions

Tags: php, apache2.4

My filemanager script has been working great up until now. It doesn't know how to handle files that don't have an extension and instead throws an error when trying to display all the files in the program and their size.

Here is the call to fetch the files and add them to the appropriate arrays.

```
$errors = array();
$items = array();
$folders = array();
$files = array();
$dir = $base_dir;
if(is_dir($dir)) {
    if($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while(($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if($file == "." || $file == "..") {
                continue;
            } else {
                $filesize = filesize($dir . "/" . $file);
                $filesize = $x10->function->realFileSize($filesize);
                $items[] = array(
                    'name' => $file,
                    'size' => $filesize,
                    'ext' => substr($file, strrpos($file, "."))
                );
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
    for($i = 0; $i < count($items); ++$i) {
        $filename = $items[$i]['name'];
        $extension = $items[$i]['ext'];
        if($extension == $filename) {
            if($filename == ".htaccess" || $filename == "magic") {
                $files[] = $items[$i];
            } else {
                $folders[] = $items[$i];
            }
        } else {
            $files[] = $items[$i];
        }
    }
} else {
    $errors[] = "1";
}
```

And I am getting this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(C:\apache\error\README,C:\apache\error\README): The directory name is invalid. (code: 267) in C:\panel\htdocs\core\functions.php:318 Stack trace: #0 C:\panel\htdocs\core\functions.php(318): RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('C:\\apache\\error...', 4096) #1 C:\panel\htdocs\filemanager.php(229): Functions->GetDirectorySize('C:\\apache\\error...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\panel\htdocs\core\functions.php on line 318
```

This is the function that is referenced to find the realFileSize of the file

```
function GetDirectorySize($path) {
    $bytestotal = 0;
    $path = realpath($path);
    if($path !== false && $path != '' && file_exists($path)) {
        foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)) as $object){
            $bytestotal += $object->getSize();
        }
    }
    return $bytestotal;
}
```

I can't find a way to handle this exception since the file `README` doesn't have an extension but it does have a size of 3KB in the directory. Is there another way to just skip these files or make them load properly? I'm at my wits end here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like this in order to catch the error:

```
try {
     foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)) as $object){

                    $bytestotal += $object->getSize();

    }
}
catch(UnexpectedValueException $e) {
            // error here print $e->getMessage();
}
```

and by the way, be aware that ext for a file called "zuumba" without extension, would be "a" when you use this code that you wrote:

```
$items[] = array(
       'name' => $file,
       'size' => $filesize,
       'ext' => substr($file, strrpos($file, "."))
);
```

Comment: I tried to use `try {} catch(UnexpectedValueException $e) {}` on it and I still get the `Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(C:\apache\error\READ...` error message.

Comment: try to move the try catch, as edited in the post, so you put the for-loop inside the try....  eventually also change your 'ext' => substr($file, strrpos($file, ".")), to this one: 'ext' => substr($file, ((strrpos($file, ".") >= 0) ? strrpos($file, ".") : 0)

Comment: Adding the try and catch before the object call works yes, but then you don't have a file size at all on the item and it gets registered as a directory instead of a file in the sorting.

Comment: to me your error message suggests, that the error is in this line and not the getsize line: `foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)) as $object){` so maybe your $path is wrong or something...or the double new or the skip_dots or whatever could go wrong on that line

Comment: path is loading every file except the ones without extensions. I found a temporary hack to make it work but ill keep researching a longer term plan. Thanks.